# Invalid post back or callback argument

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Invalid postback or callback argument. Event validation is enabled
>   using  in configuration or <%@
>   Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page. For security purposes,
>   this feature verifies that arguments to  postback or callback events
>   originate from the server control that originally rendered them. If
>   the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or callback data for  validation.  Description:
>   An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current
>   web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Invalid postback or
>   callback argument. Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page
>   EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page. For security  purposes,
>   this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events
>   originate from the server control that originally rendered them. If
>   the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to 
>   register the postback or callback data for validation.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentException: Invalid postback or callback argument. Event
>   validation is enabled using  in
>   configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.
>   For security purposes, this feature  verifies that arguments to
>   postback or callback events originate from the server control that
>   originally rendered them. If the data is valid and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to
>   register the postback or  callback data for validation.]
>   System.Web.UI.ClientScriptManager.ValidateEvent(String uniqueId,
>   String argument) +323
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.HiddenField.LoadPostData(String postDataKey,
>   NameValueCollection postCollection) +56
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData,
>   Boolean fBeforeLoad) +558
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +2496
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34237

***Some of the Points:***

1) We have migrated framework from 2.0 to 4.5.1 on production in this release after that we are facing this problem.

2) We have auto session log out when user idle for 15 minute and at the time system is giving above error.

Please help me about as it is very critical for me and continue occurring in  production.

Please let me know if you required more information from my end.

Comment: How is your "auto session log out" implemented?

Comment: can you post the code of `Page_Load` method of the exact page which is causing this error?

Comment: Javascript timer of 15 mins each tick we decreasing value of javascript variable and if user is idle for 15 mins we are logging out session by calling the log out event of button from jquery.

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack) return;
   string serverName = new Uri(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ReportUrl"]).Host;
            ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl =New Uri("http://" + serverName + "/ReportServer");
            ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials
                    = new ReportServerCredentials(
ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ReportUserName"],
ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ReportPassword"],
ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ReportDomain"]);
return;}

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (!IsPostBack) 
    { 
       string serverName = new Uri(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ReportUrl"]).Host;
       ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl =New Uri("http://" + serverName + "/ReportServer"); 
       ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials = new ReportServerCredentials( ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ReportUserName"], ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ReportPassword"], ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["ReportDomain"]);
   }
}
```

Comment: My code is working fine in local,QA,UAT and all environment expect production

Comment: I can't try it on production. all is working fine expect when session auto time out it throw "Invalid post back or callback argument"